# C# cannot get the full DataTable from Excel File

Tags: c#, excel, dataset, oledbdataadapter

when I'm trying to extract data table from excel file like this:

```
public void CopyTable(string filename)
{
    var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", filename);

    var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT col_1,   col_2,  col_3,  col_4,  col_5,  col_6    FROM[Sheet1$]", connectionString);
    var ds = new DataSet();

    adapter.Fill(ds, "ReadData");
    m_mainDt = ds.Tables["ReadData"].Copy();
}
```

I'm getting all the data except from columns 5-6.
I'm getting the titles, but not the data

[This is what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry0jd.jpg)

the excel file is .xls

this also happend when i use this query:

> ```
> SELECT *  FROM[Sheet1$]
> ```

Comment: Are any columns hidden on the spreadsheet?  If two columns are hidden then columns 5 & 6 are really 7 & 8.

Comment: im getting the columns by name , so the order and hidden columns should not interrupt
although, there are no hidden columns

Comment: Do you have a header row?  Is there data in row one in columns 5?  Oledb is dumb.  Actually it is Jet that is dumb (or too smart) which is really the excel database.  Jet tries to guess at data types and structure and often makes mistakes.  It is the root cause why using General Formatting that integers turn to dates and dates turn to integers.  Also if there is no data in column A funny things happen.

Comment: i have a header row, but all other columns seem to act ok
maybe theres another way to extract excel tables?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the correct excel workbook/worksheet?  I would put a break point after the Fill() method.  Then hover over the ds variable.  You will see a down arrow.  The click on Dataset Visualize.  You can looks at all the tables (worksheets) from pulldown.

Comment: yes i am sure
when im looking at the dataset after the fill function, it misses the two columns
super weird

Comment: I've seen some weird things with excel.  Usually these things are due to hidden version numbers for the worksheet type.  There is a way of getting the schema or the workbook which has a system table containing the names of the worksheet and there types. Sometimes when you save a worksheet to a different version of excel issues occur.   Also seen similar issues with formulas, and object like pivot tables on the worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the file was corrupted.
I've copied all the table to another file and it worked